# ¿Cómo animar un cilindro simple efecto (como en neumática) con css (o alternativas) y mejores prácticas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, jquery-ui

El mecanismo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El aire entra por un orificio y empuja el pistón comprimiendo el resorte.

La intención es hacer una animación en CSS (o alternativas si las hay) tal que al presionar un botón o en un evento ocasionado por el usuario este se mueva.

Por ejemplo lo que he intentado:

```css
#tag11 {
            width: 20%!important;
            transition: 1s;
            background: blue;
        }
        #tag11:hover {
            width: 500%!important;
            filter: hue-rotate(80deg);
            transition: 1s;
        }
```

```html
<div style="    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid;position:relative;display:flex;">
        <div id="tag11" style="width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid;position:relative;"></div>
        <div>
            <svg width='100%' height='100%' style="
        position: absolute;top:15px;">
                <line x1=0 y1=10 x2=200 y2=10 style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;" />
                Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
            </svg>
            <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 80 20" style="
    position: relative;" preserveAspectRatio=none>
                <polyline points="0,10 5,10 10,20 20,0 30,20 40,0 50,20 60,0 70,20 75,10 80,10"
                    style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;" />
                Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
            </svg>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Por ejemplo si quisiera incluir el siguente item u otros similares de circuitos neumáticos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo lo harían? No hay una forma "fácil" de graficar las flechas/vectores? y guardar 'templates' para hacer nuevos componentes css que solo requieran una pequeña modificación?

- Preferiría mover el resorte (SVG) con `width` en absoluto osea 100% como máximo pero si lo cambio a absoluto deja de compartir el tamaño con el emboló y se sale del rectángulo.
- Si se puede evitar que cambie el grosor de las líneas del resorte sería mejor, cuando llega al tope casi que la línea desaparece de lo delgada.
- De qué forma podría enlazar una variable de javascript al ancho del div que contiene al 'resorte'. y que al llegar al tope/borde active una señal/alerta.

*El objetivo en general es hacer una simulación interactiva online de un circuito neumático... También sería necesario una forma de ligar las variables como el ancho del div del resorte (arriba sale del 20% al 500% en :hover) con una variable de JavaScript. Actualmente no se como, tal vez se podría con el manejo de root en css algunos ejemplos parecen usar react js por no se casi nada de react js para lograr eso.

Comment: El objetivo en general es hacer una simulación interactiva online de un circuito neumático.

Comment: yo quitaría el último punto, pues pides recomendaciones y como sabrás esto no es muy bien visto. Por cierto muy bonita animación :D

Comment: Tal vez existan herramientas de diseño en SVG o en Canvas que faciliten este tipo de animaciones, depronto puedan recomendar alguna si conocen. (por ejemplo una que he visto famosa es figma, pero creo que no es para animaciones).

Comment: Muy interesante tu pregunta Alfredo, me gusta mucho, ** aunque pides opiniones, veo que agregas lo que trataste, esto es importante **, saludos.